# C++: passing unknown union to function as argument

Tags: c++, struct, unions

So I have something like this:

```
struct FoodType {
    union {
        int fat = 2;
    } Apple;
    union {
        int fat = 3;
    } Banana;
} FoodType;
```

And I want to write a function that takes an "unknown" FoodType as argument.

```
void eatFood(FoodType type) { /* do something */ }
```

How can this be implemented?

Comment: I would also accept an alternative way of doing something like this

Comment: A union with just one member doesn't make much sense. Did you mean a single union with `Apple` and `Banana` as its members? Anyway, you might be looking for `std::variant`

Comment: Are you sure you need to use unions? Your example doesn't really need the union at all. Either way, one way to make a function work on unknown types would be to use templates.

Comment: Also, since this is C++, you don't need FoodType at the end of the struct.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 
I basically want to be able to pass in different unions into a function and use their data in the function, no matter if it is a Banana or Apple

Comment: @Zinki thats misleading or at least can be misunderstood. To instantiate a template you need to know exactly what type you instantiate it for (at compile time)

Comment: @Zinki

Would you recommend some other way of doing this?

Comment: Any chance you could provide a more realistic example, one that actually illustrates the problem you are trying to solve? The one you have now makes no sense at all, making it difficult to understand the ultimate goal of the exercise.

Comment: please post real code, preferably a [mcve]. In your code the unions arent really unions (they have at any time always the same active member) and a `struct Foodtype` with members `Apple` and `Banana` also doesnt make much sense. Maybe you simply want an `enum` rather than unions ?!?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes! I am trying to achieve enum functionality as one can in Java

Comment: then use `enum`s not `union`s ....

Comment: Java enum is perhaps easiest to model as a) a struct or class storing some data; b) a singleton holding an array of those classes; and c) a plain C++ enum whose values serve as indexes into that array.

Comment: suggested reading: [what is the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). When asking the question it is not always easy to realize this, but here it would definitely better if you asked directly about what you want to achieve instead of asking about something you think is the solution (but actually it isnt)

Comment: To help us understand your question, do you want something like `union Foo {
        int attribute_1;
        double attribute_2;
    };
    union Bar {
        int attribute_1;
        std::string attribute_3;
    };
    void print_attribute_1(??? item){
        std::cout << "attribute 1: " << item.attribute_1 << std::endl;
    }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives to the enum solution for what you provide in your question is instantiation:

```
#include <iostream>

struct FoodType {
    FoodType(int f) : fat(f) {}
    int getFat() { return fat; }
    int fat;
};

void eatFood(const FoodType& type) { std::cout << "I ate " << type.getFat() << " grams of fat\n"; }

int main() {
    FoodType apple(2);
    eatFood(apple);
    FoodType banana(3);
    eatFood(banana);
}
```

or, for more complex situations, polymorphism can be used, but here it seems like overkill:

```
#include <iostream>

struct FoodType {
    virtual int getFat() const = 0;
};

struct Apple: FoodType {
    int getFat() const { return 2; }
};

struct Banana: FoodType {
    int getFat() const { return 3; }
};

void eatFood(const FoodType& type) { std::cout << "I ate " << type.getFat() << " grams of fat\n"; }

int main() {
    Apple apple;
    eatFood(apple);
    Banana banana;
    eatFood(banana);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
struct Food {
  enum class Type { Apple, Banana };
  int fat = 2;
  Type type = Apple;
};
```

Here you can specify the type, and you can store the `fat` value as well.

In the question's code, there is a `union` with a single member. `union` need more than one member to be useful, the members are stored at the same memory address, so you can only use one of them at the time. And both unions declared a variable with the same name and function, it seems to me that you'd only need one of those.

However, if you have something more complicated in mind, and you really need a `union`, then you should try something like this:

```
struct Food {
  enum class Type { Apple, Banana };
  Type type = Apple;
  union {
    int banana;
    double apple;
  };
};
Food food;
food.type = Food::Type::Apple;
food.apple = 2;
```

Here, you can use either the `banana` element or the `apple` element, and you'd use the `type` element to know which one to use.

But if you need that, you'd be better off using the new `std::variant` (or boost::variant) if your compiler doesn't yet support it).

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments you want enums. C++ has enums:

```
enum FoodType
{
    Apple,
    Banana
};

void EatFood(const FoodType & foodType)
{
    switch (foodType)
    {
    case Apple:
        /* do something */
        break;
    case Banana:
        /* do something */
        break;
    default:
        /* handle invalid value */
        break;
    }
}
```

If you need those integer values, do this:

```
enum FoodType
{
    Apple=2,
    Banana=3
};
```

If you want strict typing, do this:

```
enum class FoodType
{
    Apple=2,
    Banana=3
};
```

(And then in EatFood you have to use FoodType::Apple and FoodType::Banana.)